# Trouble with a function that simulates reverse attribute in python

Tags: python, list, function, reverse

I have this function to simulate `reverse()` in python:

```
My_list = [[1, 3, "s"], 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]
def listRev(list):
    list=list[::-1]
    print list
listRev(My_list)
print My_list
```

The function gives me correct reversed `list` but I expect when I print `My_list` in the last line, the code print reversed `My_list` not `My_list` itself. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Usling `list` as a veriable name is a bad idea.

Comment: @Marcin , I am agree with you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to simulate reverse, you must *modify* the list passed as a parameter to you function, not simply use a new list in your function.

When you write `list=list[::-1]` the *local* copy of the original parameter points to a new list. You should do instead :

```
def rev(l):
    l[:] = l[::-1]
    print (l)
```

The usage of `l[:]` asks Python to replace the content of the list, and not to make the variable point to a new list.

Comment: @StackOverHello if you want to do it algorithmicaly  like we do in C language you can write: `def my_list_reverse(L):
    length = len(L)    
    for i in range(length/2):
        L[i], L[length-i-1] = L[length-i-1], L[i]`

Comment: @StackOverHello your welcome! btw Good suggestion is posted by Serge Ballesta - Writing C kind of verbose code in Python would be a bad idea! - Python is a scripting language it would be better to use tools and tricks belongs to language. I just share this code with you as I have impression that you are new in Python

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by returning a list from the function

```
My_list = [[1, 3, "s"], 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]
def listRev(list):
    list=list[::-1]
    print list
    return list
My_list = listRev(My_list)
print My_list
```

This is because lists are not passed by reference in Python.

**Post Comment Edit**

If you want the function to be in place only for `My_list` even though it is very wrong and bad programming to do so, you can use this

```
My_list = [[1, 3, "s"], 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]

def listRev():
        global My_list
        My_list =  My_list[::-1]

listRev()
print My_list
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want the function itself returns me reversed My_list

Comment: Look if I delete this line: My_list = listRev(My_list) then result is My_list it self. That line is not a part of function.

Comment: @StackOverHello If you delete the line `My_list = listRev(My_list)` then you will not be calling that function. Thus `my_list` will be `My_list` itself and will not be reversed.

Comment: Yes. If I just call function like this: listRev(My_list) I just have My_list it self when I print My_list

Comment: @StackOverHello That will not be inplace as lists are not copied by reference. If you want to do that then declare `My_list` as global. and change it there itself.

Comment: @StackOverHello Congrats, and all the best